# Почему при отправке формы с использованием ajax, перезагружается страница

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-form

форма обратной связи появляется динамически. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
$сallOrderContent  = '<div id="higherFon">';
$сallOrderContent += '  <div id="escHigherFon" onclick="escHigherFon()"></div>';
$сallOrderContent += '<div id="сallOrderDiv">';
$сallOrderContent += '    <div class="container content">';
$сallOrderContent += '        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return сall(this);return false;">';
$сallOrderContent += '           <div class="form-group">';
$сallOrderContent += '              <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">';
$сallOrderContent += '                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Имя" required="required">';
$сallOrderContent += '              </div>';
$сallOrderContent += '           </div>';
$сallOrderContent += '           <div class="form-group">';
$сallOrderContent += '              <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">';
$сallOrderContent += '                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" required="required">';
$сallOrderContent += '              </div>';
$сallOrderContent += '           </div>';
$сallOrderContent += '           <div class="form-group">';
$сallOrderContent += '              <div class="col-sm-offset-4  col-sm-4" align="center">';
$сallOrderContent += '                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Позвонить!</button>';
$сallOrderContent += '              </div>';
$сallOrderContent += '           </div>';
$сallOrderContent += '        </form>';
$сallOrderContent += '    </div>';
$сallOrderContent += '</div>';
$сallOrderContent += '</div>';
```

а вот функция по которой должен отправляться запрос:

```
function сall(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $form_data = $(event).serialize(); //собераем все данные из формы
  $.ajax({
        url: "../js/communication.php",
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: $form_data,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
                   alert(data);
        }
  });  
}
```

Но как бы я не бился (уже пол дня) при нажатие на кнопку отправки сайт перезагружается.....

Comment: и что к вам на вход приходит под видом `event`?

Comment: вы вообще в курсе, что в js можно многостроковые переменные делать?

Comment: @teran можно делать многостроковые, но это не кроссбраузерное решение, особенно для старых версий IE.

Comment: @teran приходит объект HTML формы, насчёт множественных переменных не знал из-за малого опыта

Comment: и суть не в многостроковой переменной, а в том, что страница обновляется

Comment: вы там пишите у  себя `retun call(this);` однако функция `call` ничего не возвращает. а должна вернуть `false`. Вообще если используете jquery, то и обработчики пишите с его помощью `$("form").submit(function(){ .... })`; ну или скорее всего `$(....).on('submit', 'form#...', function(){ ... })`